# Postgresql user login history

Tags: postgresql

I need the postgesql user history for the entire month.

When was the last time each user was logged in?
I remember that there was a query that made the work. But not the enchilada anywhere, can someone support me with it?

Comment: to see the history of connection in postgresql must set the parameter log_connections to on in postgresql.conf file, and you will see in the logs  any connection